# Is there a naming convention to distinguish .feature files that contain plain Gherkin vs. Karate UI vs. Karate API?

Tags: naming-conventions, karate, gherkin

You can't reliably determine what a .feature file is for until you open it and look inside. That is, you don’t know if it’s just Gherkin or if it’s Karate API or UI.

Is there some convention to name files more clearly?

I'm considering using this naming convention with my team:

- `some-file.api.feature` for Karate API tests
- `some-file.ui.feature` for Karate UI tests
- `some-file.feature` for plain Gherkin/Cucumber tests

Comment: I'm voting to close because this is asking for opinions.  My own personal opinion is that you can choose any convention you please, so long as you're consistent.

Comment: I'd argue that I'm not looking for opinions. If the answer is "there is no convention", I think that's valuable information for anyone searching, and we can move forward with our own conventions.

Comment: Forgive me if this isn't the place to start the conversation, but I do think it's worthwhile to consider if there should be a convention and discuss the benefits to be gained from one. Plenty of test frameworks (e.g., Jest) have file naming conventions similar to my suggestions. I think it makes sense for Karate to adopt something similar.

Answer (score 0):

There is no convention. The reason is because you cah have "hybrid" tests which IMO is an under-appreciated test-strategy, because other tools don't support it well.

Here is an example: https://twitter.com/KarateDSL/status/1350743622312894466

And note that you can even do unit-testing: https://twitter.com/KarateDSL/status/1359369240227106816

I'll admit that Karate mocks could have benefited from a different file-extension, but we have some plans for that in the future, perhaps JS.

I think a folder naming convention should be good enough, but just my opinion.

Comment: That is a good point and a great use case. I might just use `some-file.hybrid.feature` for that sort of test. I've been separating things by folder, but the levels of nesting get irritating and it's hard to decide when to nest depending on the feature/app being tested.

Comment: @JustinDwyer cool, and I'll be interested to hear what your experiences are and perhaps you can share / blog about it 